# Can you list all the finite series that can be solved in a closed form?

Tags: sequences-and-series, big-list

I'm interested to know all the finite series that can be solved in a closed form (e.g. the geometric series)

Comment: See the wikipedia list of [common mathematical series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series).  There are of course infinitely many series that we know how to calculate in reality (*although of course some will be very similar to others in the list*) and so it isn't worth trying to list them all.

Comment: Some of the easier ones are : polynomials in falling factorials, geometric, sin and cos series, binomial coefficients, polynomials. You should learn the forward difference operator, how to convert between powers and falling factorial powers, and the method of summation by parts, so you can sum products.

Answer (score 1):

Well, consider an arbitrary sequence $x_n$, then the sequence $x_{n+1}-x_{n}$ sums up to $x_n$, i.e.
$$\sum_{i=1}^n(x_{i+1}-x_i)=x_{n+1}.$$
Therefore, any series (finite or infinite) is corresponded to a sequence.

In fact solving the sum of series (finite or infinite) is to find the corresponded sequence.